# задать другой шаг цикла в swift

Tags: swift, циклы

как задать другой шаг цикла в swift 3.0?

Есть цикл for in, там зашит по умолчанию шаг 1.

Есть цикл for, но работает ли он в swift 3.0 и позже?

Comment: Посмотри пожалуйста тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556850/how-can-i-do-a-swift-for-in-loop-with-a-step

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170203/swift-3-for-loop-with-increment

Comment: Керим, спасибо! Извини, что сразу не ответил, упорно искал решение))

Answer (score 1):

Нашел хороший вариант:

```
let array = [12, 36, 38, 66, 120, 6, 33, 67, 23, 10]

for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 2) {
      print(array[i] + array[i+1])
}
```